# How to change attribute of surrounding div/parent effectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with some radiobuttons in it. When i click on a radiobutton, i want to update two of the sorrounding containers ID attribute (a div and a table). The problem is, i need to go 4 and 6 levels up, and the only way i know how to do this is parent().parent().parent().parent() etc. 
I am looking for a better solution, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. You can see an image of how the "parent-child" tree is here:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/imgkz.png/

I already have a clickhandler etc set up.

Basicly i need to check if the table's id attribute is "answeredTable", if not i need to change it. Also i need to check if the div two levels up from the table is "answered", if not, i need to change that too.

Thanks

Comment: you can see it on the link i have provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest('#answeredTable')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parents('#answeredTable')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Using `.parent()` only selects the first parent element upon the DOM tree, selecting `.closest()` will allow you to walk up to DOM tree and match until it finds the element, while `.parents()` will return the whole parentset of the DOM and match the element in the whole parentset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) that go through multiple level of the DOM

For instance, in your example, you could get the surrounding `div` with this code:

```
$("#Q_18_2015").parents("div#answered")
```

By the way, **id should be unique**, or else, your code might probably not work. You should use classes instead.

```
<div class="answered">
```

Thus, the code would become:

```
$("#Q_18_2015").parents("div.answered")
```

provided that `Q_18_2015` is really a unique id

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is  closest http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$("element").parent(".parentClass")
```

`parents` will go up the DOM until finds the parent with class `parentClass`